# How can I increase the size of a Vector Drawable?

Tags: android, android-vectordrawable

I have created a round button using vector image which gets render from xml file

```
<vector android:height="48dp" android:tint="#FFFFFF"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0" android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:width="48dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <path android:fillColor="#FF000000" android:pathData="M15.41,7.41L14,6l-6,6 6,6 1.41,-1.41L10.83,12z"/>
</vector>
```

then I assign it into my activity_main.xml file like this

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/previous_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_navigate_before_black_24dp" />
```

I have tried different sizes inside vector xml file. but the size of the arrow stays the same. I don't want to increase the size of the button itself, but rather the size of the arrow/icon inside the button. If anyone knows I appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A vector drawable inside a fab can't appear larger than you already see, whatever size you choose for the drawable. You may however use png or jpg, if they are large enough, they will extend to the boundaries of the fab.